# Javascript: Easier way to format numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I'm trying to format various numbers on my page.  These numbers either represent a price, a change in price, or a percentage.  I know Javascript has functions to limit the number of decimal places, but is there any support for other types of formatting, such as grouping numbers with commas, controlling whether or not the +/- is shown, etc?  Here's what I have so far:

```
var FORMATTER = {
    price       : function(value) { return '$' + value.toFixed(2); },
    pricePer    : function(value) { return (value * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'; },
    priceChg    : function(value) { return (value >= 0 ? '+' : '-') + '$' + Math.abs(value).toFixed(2); }
};
```

It works OK, but it'd like to add commas to the 'price' formatter, and you can see that there's a hack in the 'priceChg' formatter where I try to move the +/- sign in front of the '$' sign.

Basically, I'm hoping there is some library out there (jQuery is OK) that emulates Java's DecimalFormat class.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's the NUMBERFORMATTER jQuery plugin, details below:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

From the above link:

> This plugin is a NumberFormatter
>   plugin. Number formatting is likely
>   familiar to anyone who's worked with
>   server-side code like Java or PHP and
>   who has worked with
>   internationalization.

EDIT: Replaced the link with a more direct one.

Comment: You should probably link to http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter instead.

Comment: is this plugin deprecated?

Comment: The link is dead due to the jQuery plugin site going away. Is this the same plugin that is located at https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

Comment: this is the latest github link: https://github.com/hardhub/jquery-numberformatter

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no built-in support for number formatting, but googling will turn up loads of code snippets that will do this for you.

EDIT: I missed the last sentence of your post. Try http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/StringFormat for a jQuery solution.

Comment: He's not asking for built-in support, he's asking for a library.

Comment: The post says "I know Javascript has functions to limit the number of decimal places, but is there any support for other types of formatting". Reads like he's asking about built-in support, if you don't read the whole post like me :)

Answer (score 3):

Just finished up a js library for formatting numbers [Numeral.js](http://adamwdraper.github.com/Numeral-js/).  It handles decimals, dollars, percentages and even time formatting.

Comment: Thanks adamwdraper! I needed a solution that didn't involve jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Also try [dojo.number](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/number) which has built-in localization support.  It is a much closer analog to Java's NumberFormat/DecimalFormat

Answer (score 0):

Here's the YUI version if anyone's interested:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Number.html

```
var str = YAHOO.util.Number.format(12345, { thousandsSeparator: ',' } );
```