# Format numbers in JavaScript similar to C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, numbers

Is there a simple way to format numbers in JavaScript, similar to the formatting methods available in C# (or VB.NET) via `ToString("format_provider")` or `String.Format()`?

Comment: You should probably have a look at the JQuery NUMBERFORMATTER plugin: [Jquery Number Formatter](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) And this question: [Javascript easier way to format numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726144/javascript-easier-way-to-format-numbers/)

Comment: @Darhuuk, and 32.6 million of them are terrible...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449580/jquery-number-formatting-issue/8449695#8449695

Answer (score 76):

**Generally**

- [Formatting numbers in JavaScript](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html)
- [Formatting numbers for currency display and more.](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221092535/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/rajeshatdotnet/archive/2008/04/05/121058.aspx)

**In jQuery**

- [autoNumeric](https://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) (a decent number formatter & input helper with locale support for jQuery 1.5+)
- [jQuery Format](https://www.asual.com/jquery/format/) (a clientSide implementation of Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html))
- [jquery-numberformatter (number formatter with locale support)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160116234619/https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)

Comment: A word of warning: The jQuery number formatter you link to (I tried with v1.1.0) is completely broken and useless. As in: It does not work *at all*. Here is a decent formatting plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/format/

Comment: @Tomalak, You should post that as an answer.  That's definitely the best number formatter plugin I've used.  I wish there were documentation outside of the unit tests though.

Comment: @Brad That's a little late. But good to hear that you've found it useful!

Comment: @Tomalak It's never too late. Here I am looking at this more than a year later!

Comment: And me nearly three years later!

Comment: What about percent formatting? Does asual.com/jquer/format handles it?

Comment: autoNumeric is quite full-featured and recently updated to 1.8.0.

Comment: +1 for autoNumeric, though as of this writing (v 1.8.1), input types other than <input> "are NOT supported including HTML 5 number type[s]."

Comment: ...And as of that writing, I've discovered "accounting.js" which for many use cases is an even more effective solution.

Answer (score 49):

Yes, there is definitely a way to format numbers properly in javascript, for example:

```
var val=2489.8237

val.toFixed(3) //returns 2489.824 (round up)
val.toFixed(2) //returns 2489.82
val.toFixed(7) //returns 2489.8237000 (padding)
```

With the use of variablename.**toFixed** .

And there is another function `toPrecision()` .
For more detail you also can visit

http://raovishal.blogspot.com/2012/01/number-format-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 25):

Here's a simple JS function to add commas to an integer number in string format.  It will handle whole numbers or decimal numbers.  You can pass it either a number or a string.  It obviously returns a string.

```
function addCommas(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        first = main.charAt(0),
        i;

    if (first === '-') {
        main = main.slice(1);
        len = main.length;    
    } else {
        first = "";
    }
    i = len - 1;
    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put sign back
    output = first + output;
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Here's a set of test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6y57j/

You can see it being used in this previous jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sMnjT/.  You can find functions that will handle decimal numbers too with a simple Google search for "javascript add commas".

Converting a number to a string can be done many ways.  The easiest is just to add it to a string:

```
var myNumber = 3;
var myStr = "" + myNumber;   // "3"
```

Within, the context of your jsFiddle, you'd get commas into the counter by changing this line:

```
jTarget.text(current);
```

to this:

```
jTarget.text(addCommas(current));
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CbjSX/

Comment: @blackessej - I added more onto the end of my answer that shows how addCommas can be added to your fiddle.

Comment: Added support for decimal numbers in the `addCommas()` function so it works for numbers with a decimal part.

Comment: Not so hot for negative numbers ):

Comment: @Kristopher - I added support for negative numbers.

Comment: Very nice. I'm using this now.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a simple function (not yet another jQuery plugin needed!!) that converts a number to a decimal separated string or an empty string if the number wasn't a number to begin with:

```
function format(x) {
    return isNaN(x)?"":x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

`format(578999);` results in `578,999`

`format(10);` results in `10`

if you want to have a decimal point instead of a comma simply replace the comma in the code with a decimal point.

One of the comments correctly stated this only works for integers, with a few small adaptions you can make it work for floating points as well:

```
function format(x) {
    if(isNaN(x))return "";

    n= x.toString().split('.');
    return n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")+(n.length>1?"."+n[1]:"");
}
```

Comment: If you split the floating point part first, then do this with the integer, and then add the flowing point part again it should also work on fp's

Comment: `"412.8".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");` returns `412.8`. I think it could return `412.80`

Answer (score 9):

Here are some solutions, all pass the test suite, test suite and benchmark included, if you want copy and paste to test, try [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/SteelyWing/85fdcbe084c332596179).

## Method 0 (RegExp)

Base on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428340/1877620, but fix if there is no decimal point.

```
if (typeof Number.prototype.format === 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.format = function (precision) {
        if (!isFinite(this)) {
            return this.toString();
        }

        var a = this.toFixed(precision).split('.');
        a[0] = a[0].replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$&,');
        return a.join('.');
    }
}
```

## Method 1

```
if (typeof Number.prototype.format1 === 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.format1 = function (precision) {
        if (!isFinite(this)) {
            return this.toString();
        }

        var a = this.toFixed(precision).split('.'),
            // skip the '-' sign
            head = Number(this < 0);

        // skip the digits that's before the first thousands separator 
        head += (a[0].length - head) % 3 || 3;

        a[0] = a[0].slice(0, head) + a[0].slice(head).replace(/\d{3}/g, ',$&');
        return a.join('.');
    };
}
```

## Method 2 (Split to Array)

```
if (typeof Number.prototype.format2 === 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.format2 = function (precision) {
        if (!isFinite(this)) {
            return this.toString();
        }

        var a = this.toFixed(precision).split('.');

        a[0] = a[0]
            .split('').reverse().join('')
            .replace(/\d{3}(?=\d)/g, '$&,')
            .split('').reverse().join('');

        return a.join('.');
    };
}
```

## Method 3 (Loop)

```
if (typeof Number.prototype.format3 === 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.format3 = function (precision) {
        if (!isFinite(this)) {
            return this.toString();
        }

        var a = this.toFixed(precision).split('');
        a.push('.');

        var i = a.indexOf('.') - 3;
        while (i > 0 && a[i-1] !== '-') {
            a.splice(i, 0, ',');
            i -= 3;
        }

        a.pop();
        return a.join('');
    };
}
```

## Example

```
console.log('======== Demo ========')
var n = 0;
for (var i=1; i<20; i++) {
    n = (n * 10) + (i % 10)/100;
    console.log(n.format(2), (-n).format(2));
}
```

## Separator

If we want custom thousands separator or decimal separator, use replace():

```
123456.78.format(2).replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ' ');
```

## Test suite

```
function assertEqual(a, b) {
    if (a !== b) {
        throw a + ' !== ' + b;
    }
}

function test(format_function) {
    console.log(format_function);
    assertEqual('NaN', format_function.call(NaN, 0))
    assertEqual('Infinity', format_function.call(Infinity, 0))
    assertEqual('-Infinity', format_function.call(-Infinity, 0))

    assertEqual('0', format_function.call(0, 0))
    assertEqual('0.00', format_function.call(0, 2))
    assertEqual('1', format_function.call(1, 0))
    assertEqual('-1', format_function.call(-1, 0))
    // decimal padding
    assertEqual('1.00', format_function.call(1, 2))
    assertEqual('-1.00', format_function.call(-1, 2))
    // decimal rounding
    assertEqual('0.12', format_function.call(0.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('0.1235', format_function.call(0.123456, 4))
    assertEqual('-0.12', format_function.call(-0.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-0.1235', format_function.call(-0.123456, 4))
    // thousands separator
    assertEqual('1,234', format_function.call(1234.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('12,345', format_function.call(12345.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('123,456', format_function.call(123456.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('1,234,567', format_function.call(1234567.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('12,345,678', format_function.call(12345678.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('123,456,789', format_function.call(123456789.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('-1,234', format_function.call(-1234.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('-12,345', format_function.call(-12345.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('-123,456', format_function.call(-123456.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('-1,234,567', format_function.call(-1234567.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('-12,345,678', format_function.call(-12345678.123456, 0))
    assertEqual('-123,456,789', format_function.call(-123456789.123456, 0))
    // thousands separator and decimal
    assertEqual('1,234.12', format_function.call(1234.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('12,345.12', format_function.call(12345.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('123,456.12', format_function.call(123456.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('1,234,567.12', format_function.call(1234567.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('12,345,678.12', format_function.call(12345678.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('123,456,789.12', format_function.call(123456789.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-1,234.12', format_function.call(-1234.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-12,345.12', format_function.call(-12345.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-123,456.12', format_function.call(-123456.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-1,234,567.12', format_function.call(-1234567.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-12,345,678.12', format_function.call(-12345678.123456, 2))
    assertEqual('-123,456,789.12', format_function.call(-123456789.123456, 2))
}

console.log('======== Testing ========');
test(Number.prototype.format);
test(Number.prototype.format1);
test(Number.prototype.format2);
test(Number.prototype.format3);
```

## Benchmark

```
function benchmark(f) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    f();
    return new Date().getTime() - start;
}

function benchmark_format(f) {
    console.log(f);
    time = benchmark(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            f.call(123456789, 0);
            f.call(123456789, 2);
        }
    });
    console.log(time.format(0) + 'ms');
}

async = [];
function next() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        f = async.shift();
        f && f();
        next();
    }, 10);
}

console.log('======== Benchmark ========');
async.push(function () { benchmark_format(Number.prototype.format); });
async.push(function () { benchmark_format(Number.prototype.format1); });
async.push(function () { benchmark_format(Number.prototype.format2); });
async.push(function () { benchmark_format(Number.prototype.format3); });
next();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use jQuery, take a look at [Numeral.js](http://adamwdraper.github.com/Numeral-js/)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, converting an integer into string in JS is really simple:

```
// Start off with a number
var number = 42;
// Convert into a string by appending an empty (or whatever you like as a string) to it
var string = 42+'';
// No extra conversion is needed, even though you could actually do
var alsoString = number.toString();
```

If you have a number as a string and want it to be turned to an integer, you have to use the `parseInt(string)` for integers and `parseFloat(string)` for floats. Both of these functions then return the desired integer/float. Example:

```
// Start off with a float as a string
var stringFloat = '3.14';
// And an int as a string
var stringInt = '42';

// typeof stringInt  would give you 'string'

// Get the real float from the string
var realFloat = parseFloat(someFloat);
// Same for the int
var realInt = parseInt(stringInt);

// but typeof realInt  will now give you 'number'
```

What exactly are you trying to append etc, remains unclear to me from your question.

Comment: thanks for that.  Did you view my code on jsfiddle?  I basically understand how to convert an integer to a string - what I don't understand, since I'm not very proficient at js yet, is how to do it with the context of the script that I'm using.  Any further insights?

Comment: @blackessej I don't understand what has to be appended after a coma. If it's just counting, I'd suggest using float, and if you want 2 decimal places for example, you could simply increment the number by 0.01 each time, not by 1.

Comment: you'll really have to bear with me - I don't understand how to convert my number to a string within my code.

Comment: Please be sure to use `parseInt(..., 10)` though, to make sure base 10 is used.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. He wants (and so do I) to turn `XXXXXXX.YYYY` into `X,XXX,XXX.YYYY`.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/javascript-number-formatter/ :

- Short, fast, flexible yet standalone. Only 75 lines including MIT license info, blank lines & comments.
- Accept standard number formatting like #,##0.00 or with negation -000.####.
- Accept any country format like # ##0,00, #,###.##, #'###.## or any type of non-numbering symbol.
- Accept any numbers of digit grouping. #,##,#0.000 or #,###0.## are all valid.
- Accept any redundant/fool-proof formatting. ##,###,##.# or 0#,#00#.###0# are all OK.
- Auto number rounding.
- Simple interface, just supply mask & value like this: format( "0.0000", 3.141592)

**UPDATE**

As say **Tomáš Zato** here one line solution:

```
(666.0).toLocaleString()
numObj.toLocaleString([locales [, options]])
```

which described in ECMA-262 5.1 Edition:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.3
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

and will work in future versions of browsers...

Comment: Because I don't want to use library when I just need a simple function...?

Comment: Is that simple function: https://code.google.com/p/javascript-number-formatter/source/browse/format.js ? I think - yes (60 lines of code).

Comment: You have very properly said *"I think"*. That's because whether something is simple or not is matter of opinion. There is no absolute truth amongst opinions giving us chance to have endless arguments.

Comment: This is SO and your behavior is typical among SO users.

Comment: Seems you're really ready to go flaming over my comment. Don't you have anything better to do? Anyway, a one liner cross-country code is `(6666.0).toLocaleString()`. And you're welcome to call any behavior whatever you want if you're aware that such comments are out of topic and might disappear. Also please stop trying to make me undownvote your post. You're doomed to fail because I didn't downvote it... I prever comments over downvotes.

Comment: Also I agree with your "*When downvote write why!*". However I'm dissapoined that you actually don't seem to want to know the answer. You just want to argue.

Comment: This library pushed to Google code just in time when ECMA-262
5.1 Edition released (June 2011). `toLocaleString()` is good thing and I don't know about it. Now I understand your arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
var flt = '5.99';
var nt = '6';

var rflt = parseFloat(flt);
var rnt = parseInt(nt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **JQuery**.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    //Only number and one dot
    function onlyDecimal(element, decimals)
    {
        $(element).keypress(function(event)
        {
            num = $(this).val() ;
            num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num ;
            if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57))
            {
                event.preventDefault();

            }
            if($(this).val() == parseFloat(num).toFixed(decimals))
            {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }

     onlyDecimal("#TextBox1", 3) ;



});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a decimal with 2 numbers after the comma, you could just use:

```
function nformat(a) {
   var b = parseInt(parseFloat(a)*100)/100;
   return b.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest [numbro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numbro) for locale based formatting and [number-format.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-format.js) for the general case. A combination of the two depending on use-case may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version:

```
$.fn.digits = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).text();
        var decimal = "";
        if (value) {
            var pos = value.indexOf(".");
            if (pos >= 0) {
                decimal = value.substring(pos);
                value = value.substring(0, pos);
            }
            if (value) {
                value = value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(decimal)) value = (value + decimal);
                $(this).text(value);
            }
        }
        else {
            value = $(this).val()
            if (value) {
                var pos = value.indexOf(".");
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    decimal = value.substring(pos);
                    value = value.substring(0, pos);
                }
                if (value) {
                    value = value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                    if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(decimal)) value = (value + decimal);
                    $(this).val(value);
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple function, maybe someone can use it

```
function secsToTime(secs){
  function format(number){
    if(number===0){
      return '00';
    }else {
      if (number < 10) {
          return '0' + number
      } else{
          return ''+number;
      }
    }
  }

  var minutes = Math.floor(secs/60)%60;
  var hours = Math.floor(secs/(60*60))%24;
  var days = Math.floor(secs/(60*60*24));
  var seconds = Math.floor(secs)%60;

  return (days>0? days+"d " : "")+format(hours)+':'+format(minutes)+':'+format(seconds);
}
```

this can generate the followings outputs:

- 5d 02:53:39
- 4d 22:15:16
- 03:01:05
- 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to format number for view rather than for calculation you can use this

```
function numberFormat( number ){

    var digitCount = (number+"").length;
    var formatedNumber = number+"";
    var ind = digitCount%3 || 3;
    var temparr = formatedNumber.split('');

    if( digitCount > 3 && digitCount <= 6 ){

        temparr.splice(ind,0,',');
        formatedNumber = temparr.join('');

    }else if (digitCount >= 7 && digitCount <= 15) {
        var temparr2 = temparr.slice(0, ind);
        temparr2.push(',');
        temparr2.push(temparr[ind]);
        temparr2.push(temparr[ind + 1]);
        // temparr2.push( temparr[ind + 2] ); 
        if (digitCount >= 7 && digitCount <= 9) {
            temparr2.push(" million");
        } else if (digitCount >= 10 && digitCount <= 12) {
            temparr2.push(" billion");
        } else if (digitCount >= 13 && digitCount <= 15) {
            temparr2.push(" trillion");

        }
        formatedNumber = temparr2.join('');
    }
    return formatedNumber;
}
```

**Input:** {Integer} Number

**Outputs:** {String} Number

22,870            => if number 22870

22,87 million     => if number 2287xxxx  (x can be whatever)

22,87 billion     => if number 2287xxxxxxx

22,87 trillion    => if number 2287xxxxxxxxxx

You get the idea

Answer (score 0):

To further jfriend00's answer (I dont't have enough points to comment) I have extended his/her answer to the following:

```js
function log(args) {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "object") {
            str += JSON.stringify(arguments[i]);
        } else {
            str += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

Number.prototype.addCommas = function (str) {
    if (str === undefined) {
     str = this;
    }
    
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        first = main.charAt(0),
        i;
    
    if (first === '-') {
        main = main.slice(1);
        len = main.length;    
    } else {
       first = "";
    }
    i = len - 1;
    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put sign back
    output = first + output;
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}

var testCases = [
    1, 12, 123, -1234, 12345, 123456, -1234567, 12345678, 123456789,
    -1.1, 12.1, 123.1, 1234.1, -12345.1, -123456.1, -1234567.1, 12345678.1, 123456789.1
];
 
for (var i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
 log(testCases[i].addCommas());
}
 
/*for (var i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
    log(Number.addCommas(testCases[i]));
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:
So you will not only format the number but you can also pass as a parameter how many decimal digits to display, you set a custom decimal and mile separator.

```
function format(number, decimals = 2, decimalSeparator = '.', thousandsSeparator = ',') {
    const roundedNumber = number.toFixed(decimals);
    let integerPart = '', fractionalPart = '';
    if (decimals == 0) {
        integerPart = roundedNumber;
        decimalSeparator = '';
    } else {
        let numberParts = roundedNumber.split('.');
        integerPart = numberParts[0];
        fractionalPart = numberParts[1];
    }
    integerPart = integerPart.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, `$1${thousandsSeparator}`);
    return `${integerPart}${decimalSeparator}${fractionalPart}`;
}
```

Use:

```
let min = 1556454.0001;
let max = 15556982.9999;
console.time('number format');
for (let i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
    let randomNumber = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    let formated = format(randomNumber, 4, ',', '.'); // formated number

    console.debug('number: ', randomNumber, 'formated: ', formated);
}
console.timeEnd('number format');
```

Comment: Remember to use === instead of == where you are checking `if (decimals == 0) {` - it should be `if (decimals === 0) {`