# javascript split string at parts

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)

I have a string represents a number: "3507654"
I need to split it on a parts, by 3, e.g "3 507 654"

Number can be any value, but always a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
"3507654".replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, "$1 ")
```

But this is not very efficient since it’s O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: nice answer.  regex FTW.

Comment: … and there's a leading space if the number has 3n digits.

Comment: Real nice answer. Definitely +1

Comment: @Kenny: I was just about to mention how to fix that, but Gumbo updated his answer to include the fix already. +1.

Comment: thanks, very elegants and hackers :) +1