# How to format numbers dynamically in input field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'd like to format a number *on the fly as user types*. There are a couple of usefull plugins like jquery.maskedinput, but none of them is able to create a dynamic mask that would work with all of scenarios:

- 1000000 -> 1 000 000
- 100000 -> 100 000
- 10000 -> 10 000

And so on. Perhaps there is a clever way to achieve this with jquery dynamically as user types? Or maybe I just missed one plugin that does this? :)

Comment: This must be when the user types and not onblur?

Comment: Yes, since the field will contain a large number it's a help for a user not to make a mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice regexp to take the string apart properly:
[javascript split string at parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280785/javascript-split-string-at-parts/3280810#3280810)

And here is a small experimental plugin that seems to work ok now (thanks to Segaja from #jquery on freenode!):

https://gist.github.com/1047003

To use it just include it in the page code and add:

```
$("input.someclass").formatInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice plugin that can both format and parse numbers like this. [jquery-numberformatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)

What you would want to do is when the value of the field changes, immediately parse the field value, and set it back into the format you desire.

Comment: This solution is too heavy - I have to include the plugin script and jshashtable script as a dependency, whereas I need to parse 3-5 fields. Each extra dependency is a penalty in google page speed score. I'd rather go for some code snippet or a short plugin I could include in page code directly :)