# JavaScript function that can produce same results as PHP function number_format

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)

I'm in search of a JavaScript function that can produce the same results as the PHP function `number_format(150000,0,',',',');` is there a JavaScript function available to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481