# JavaScript how to display numbers

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I computed a number in JavaScript function.

Example:

```
var price = 1000;
var commission = 200;

var total = price + commission
```

After I added these two I want to show the total as `1,200` (put `,` in between 3 digits).

Comment: Please do a google search before posting the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

> This functionality is not built into JavaScript, so custom code needs to be used. The following is one way of adding commas to a number, and returning a string.

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: "It's better to quote the relevant section here and include the link as reference than to only provide the link." Thanks for the heads up Bill, will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCommas(price) {
    var x = (parseFloat((isNaN(price) ? 0 : price)).toFixed(2)+'').split('.');
    var x3 = x[0].substr(-3);
    for(var i=x[0].length-3; i>0; i=i-3)
        x3 = x[0].substr((i < 3 ? 0 : (i-3)), (i < 3 ? i : 3))+","+x3;
    return x3 + (x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '');
}
```

When you do just want an integer value instead of an float with 2 digits, just change the last line to

```
return x3;
```

Answer (score 0):

often i use `toLocaleString` depents abit on what im doing (some parts of the world use comma insted of dot and visa for delimiting

```
var total = (price + commission).toLocaleString()
```