# ECMAScript Internationalization API with node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-intl

Is there a way to use the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/)  with nodejs?

For now, i only need the timezone support:

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
```

which works very well with chrome, but not with node. 
Are there any options like --harmony to activate it?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, the title implies that you want the `intl` module.  Unfortunately, timezone support is one of the remaining unimplemented features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internationalization is turned off in v8 when built for node.js.  The reason is that the library that provides it significantly increases the size of the node binary for a small perceived gain.  You can turn it back on if you're willing to build node from source.  First you'll have to check out the github repo (https://github.com/joyent/node) and then do the following from the repo root:

```
svn checkout --force --revision 214189 \
    http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/deps/third_party/icu46 \
    deps/v8/third_party/icu46
./configure --with-icu-path=deps/v8/third_party/icu46/icu.gyp
make
make install
```

These instructions are from the README.md of that repo, which can be read at https://github.com/joyent/node