# Convert number into xx.xx million format?

Tags: php, numbers, format

Is there a simple way to convert a high number e.g. 14120000 into 14.12 million format with PHP?

I've been looking at number_format but it doesn't seem to offer this function, also thought about sub_str to separate the digits out, but thought there might be a better way?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I've been looking at number_format but it doesn't seem to offer this function, also thought about sub_str to separate the digits out, but thought there might be a better way?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't know where to start and is asking for advice? Is that such a hard concept to grasp?

Comment: Closed as not a real question? Can someone tell me what is not real about this question? Just so I know for the future - thanks.

Comment: Found a similar question here which has been accepted as valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript . It might be more constructive and welcoming for newbies like me to suggest how to improve my question before immediately downvoting me and closing the question without explanation.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question & one I was going to ask. Not sure why it was closed. The fact that someone could actually answer it, proves that it was a valid question more than anything else.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what's up with SO anymore

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this from, https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#89888:

```
<?php 
    function nice_number($n) {
        // first strip any formatting;
        $n = (0+str_replace(",", "", $n));

        // is this a number?
        if (!is_numeric($n)) return false;

        // now filter it;
        if ($n > 1000000000000) return round(($n/1000000000000), 2).' trillion';
        elseif ($n > 1000000000) return round(($n/1000000000), 2).' billion';
        elseif ($n > 1000000) return round(($n/1000000), 2).' million';
        elseif ($n > 1000) return round(($n/1000), 2).' thousand';

        return number_format($n);
    }

echo nice_number('14120000'); //14.12 million

?>
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Thought there might be a more general PHP function for this, but obviously not!

Comment: Shouldn't you cite to this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#89888

Comment: Alternative solution: http://kahthong.com/2013/01/php-format-currency-nearest-thousands-such-kilos-millions-billions-and-trillions

Comment: Why did you close this question? The algorythm above is ugly and better solutions are possible.