# Formating Comment Count in WordPress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, number-formatting

I have the following php I use in Wordpress on the frontend to display how many total comments my blog has. So say for example would render to display something to this effect: 1,265,788

```
<?php
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
echo number_format($comments_count->total_comments);
?>
```

What I would like to do is format the number better. So instead of it saying I have 1,265,788 comments, it will say I have 1,265M comments.

I tried the following code as recommended by another post, but does not work either. It echo's the full number.

```
<?php
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
if ($comments_count->total_comments < 1000000) {
    // Anything less than a million
    $n_format = number_format($comments_count->total_comments);
    echo $n_format;
} else if ($comments_count->total_comments < 1000000000) {
    // Anything less than a billion
    $n_format = number_format($comments_count->total_comments / 1000000, 3) . 'M';
    echo $n_format;
} else {
    // At least a billion
    $n_format = number_format($comments_count->total_comments / 1000000000, 3) . 'B';
    echo $n_format;
}
?>
```

So no, this is not a duplicate question. Previous answers are of absolute no help to me. I tried exactly like the answers said and the output I get is the full number like the original top code gives me.

Anyone have an idea how I can achieve this and can show me a sample please.

Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a good option for you in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221694/convert-number-into-xx-xx-million-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually above code is working fine and output is `1.266M`

Hard coded example:

```
$number = 1265788;
if ($number < 1000000) {
    // Anything less than a million
    $n_format = number_format($number);
    echo $n_format;
} else if ($number < 1000000000) {
    // Anything less than a billion
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000, 3) . 'M';
    echo $n_format;
} else {
    // At least a billion
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000000, 3) . 'B';
    echo $n_format;
}
```

Dynamic:

```
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
$number = $comments_count->total_comments;
if ($number < 1000000) {
    // Anything less than a million
    $n_format = number_format($number);
    echo $n_format;
} else if ($number < 1000000000) {
    // Anything less than a billion
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000, 3) . 'M';
    echo $n_format;
} else {
    // At least a billion
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000000, 3) . 'B';
    echo $n_format;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But now I get 0.000M. I used <?php
if ($number = $comments_count->total_comments) {
    $n_format = number_format($number);
    echo $n_format;
} else if ($number < 1000000000) {
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000, 3) . 'M';
    echo $n_format;
} else {
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000000, 3) . 'B';
    echo $n_format;
}
?>

Comment: I try this and get 0. <?php
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
$number = $comments_count->total_comments;
if ($number < 1000000) {
    // Anything less than a million
    $n_format = number_format($number);
    echo $n_format;
} else if ($number < 1000000000) {
    // Anything less than a billion
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000, 3) . 'M';
    echo $n_format;
} else {
    // At least a billion
    $n_format = number_format($number / 1000000000, 3) . 'B';
    echo $n_format;
}
?>

Comment: That means your comment count is 0

Comment: No my global comment count is over 1 million

Comment: Are you initializing the `$comments_count` like this `$comments_count = wp_count_comments();` before `$number = $comments_count->total_comments;`? I have updated the answer use Dynamic: example

Comment: I tried the Dynamic example you posted and it shows the entire comment count (ie: 1,265,788 ) but still doesnt seem to want to shorten the comment count to 1,265M

Comment: Your answer works outside of the site, but inside of it it dont. I believe something is wrong in my functions.php file. Thanks anyways