# php function for multiple use

Tags: php, function, format

Is there a way to use if/else code multiple times for different variables? This is just a example because I don't know how to search for it or if it even exist? Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function value(){
if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
    $value = number_format($value / 1000,1) . 'K';
  } elseif ($value > 999999) {
    $value = number_format($value / 1000000,1) . 'mln';
  } else {
    $value;
  }
}

  value($variable1);
  value($variable2);
  value($variable3);
```

Comment: Php providing switch function for the task

Comment: Does this function work as you expect?

Comment: You need to define a call argument in the function declaration. That is the whole point of functions.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221694/convert-number-into-xx-xx-million-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a call argument (parameter) in the function declaration. That is the whole point of functions:

```
<?php
function formatValue($value){
if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
    return number_format($value / 1000,1) . 'K';
  } elseif ($value > 999999) {
    return number_format($value / 1000000,1) . 'mln';
  } else {
    return $value;
  }
}

$someValue = 8888;
var_dump(formatValue($someValue));
var_dump(formatValue(555555555));
var_dump(formatValue((2*$someValue)+1000000));
var_dump(formatValue(-200));
```

The output of above code is:

```
string(4) "8.9K"
string(8) "555.6mln"
string(6) "1.0mln"
int(-200)
```

Answer (score 0):

The value function has to take one parameter ($value).

Your function should be

```
    function value(&$value){
       if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
          $value = number_format($value / 1000,1) . 'K';
       } elseif ($value > 999999) {
          $value = number_format($value / 1000000,1) . 'mln';
       } else {
          $value;
       }
}
```

You have to pass $value as a reference since you assign something to it and you want to get it outside the function.

You could also return number_format($value / 1000,1) . 'K'; instead of assigning it to $value.