# Regex to put a Leading Zero in Front of all Unfinished Decimals || .5 = 0.5

Tags: javascript, regex, string, decimal

I am trying to create a regular expression that turns a string like "5+.34+3", into "5+0.34+3". Basically I am trying to add a leading zero in front of all decimals that DON'T have a leading zero already.

---

### **Some Examples**

| Input | Output | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ".34" | "0.34" | (added zero in front of decimal) |
| "1.45" | "1.45" | (No change) |
| "66+.33+22+.32" | "66+0.33+22+0.32" | (added zero in front of all decimals without one |
| "5+.22" | "5+0.22" | (added zero in front of .22) |

### **Thank you so much for trying to figure this out!**

(If there is another question on stack overflow like this one, please let me know so I can take this question down)

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345184/1207049

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `your_string.replace(/(^|\D)\.(\d+)/g, "$10.$2")`

Comment: In response to Maciej Los, I am creating a calculator that takes a string as input and returns another string as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One wants to replace any decimal separator which is not prepended/prefixed by a digit character. Thus, a valid approach was to use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) running a regex which features a [negative lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) and which does [capture](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) the character of the decimal separator.

The regex looks like this ... [`/(?<!\d)(\.)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/ttRlXj/1) ... and reads like that ...

- `/ ... /g` ... apply the pattern globally by ...
- `/ ... (\.)/g` ... capturing the intended separator character ...
- `/ (?<!\d) ... /g` ... which is not (`<!`) prepended by a single digit (`\d`) ...

```js
const sample = `
  .34
  1.45
  66+.33+22+.32
  5+.22 5+0.22 5+.22`;

const regXNonLeadingDigitDecimalSeparator = (/(?<!\d)(\.)/g);

console.log(
  'original ...',
  sample
);
console.log(
  'sanitized ...',
  sample.replace(regXNonLeadingDigitDecimalSeparator, '0$1')
);

console.log(
  'some other separator sample ...\n',
  '0,45; ,78; 0,78; 0.9; .9 =>',
  '0,45; ,78; 0,78; 0.9; .9'.replace((/(?<!\d)(,)/g), '0$1')
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since I'm always eager to learn, the downvote could come with a comment about where the approach needs to be improved.

Comment: I concur. Some people should not be allowed to vote or downvotes should be more expensive without a comment. I assume the downvoter thought we should not answer this question because of lack of effort from the asker's side and we should be punished for our wish to help. Anyway, I voted you up.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to a regex with the possibility to manipulate even more

```js
const floats = [".34", "1.45", "66+.33+22+.32", "5+.22"].map(str => {
 return  str.split('+').map(part => part.startsWith(".") ? "0"+part : part).join('+')
})
console.log(floats)
```

Comment: Any reason for an uncommented downvote? The script works and can be used for other manipulations

Comment: Yeah, it is a weird behaviour. I wish ppl would be kinder