# Reduce messy number in JQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)

I have number 2.3455555555555555 I want to get it only 2.34 by using jQuery. I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(2.3455555555555555).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: @elclanrs thnx for the braces