# Allocation of digits in the price list

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)
>   [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

I want to separate the zeros of the gap in the price list.

As example

current: 150000
wanted: **150 000**

current: 2730000
wanted: **2 730 000**

Using jQuery and all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera)

UPD I want to dynamically add spaces when entering numbers

```
Step by step: user entered 10, in input 10
100 - 100
1000 - 1 000
10000 - 10 000
100000 - 100 000
1000000 - 1 000 000
```

UPD I used regex
`val.replace(/(\S)(?=(\S\S\S)+(?!\S))/g, "$1 ");`
It's correct works in FF only

Comment: [What have your tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/xTMzv/

Comment: Accidentally pressed to maintain the post. Nothing a minus!

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is your number, use following regex:

```
n.toString().replace( /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ' );
```

Comment: I don't understand that regex, but it seems to work `:)`

Comment: Doesn't work! 1 2 3 4 5 6 789

Comment: @StackStack quite surprised that it doesn't work for you. I tested this with latest versions of Safari, FF, Chrome, Opera on Mac. Works in all. Check the jsbin http://jsbin.com/umored/2/watch Suspect it has to do with some version of IE.