# JavaScript code returning to many digits after decimal

Tags: javascript, html

I have code where I need the number that arrives to return 1 or 2 digits after decimal not 15 like it does now, here is what I have.

```
function GetDiff (dt) { 
    sMins = " Min";
    sHours = " Hrs";
    sDays = " Days";

    if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) < 1440 ) {
        if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) <= 60 ) {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) + sMins);
        }
        else
        {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/60) + sHours);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/1440) + sDays);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use google: ["_javascript round number two places_"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1726630/778118).

Comment: Another [useful link...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FNumber%2FtoFixed) and [another...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision).

Comment: When I hover over the upvote arrow it says: "_This question shows research effort..._" Not sure why anybody would choose to click on that button after reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! Now Whenever I entered .tofixed it wouldn't work, but like I said this is a function for code later on in the script so idk.

```
                    function GetDiff (dt) { 
        sMins = " Min";
    sHours = " Hrs";
    sDays = " Days";

    if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) < 1440 ) {
        if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) <= 60 ) {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) + sMins);
        }
        else
        {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/60)*10)/10) + sHours);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/1440)*10)/10) + sDays);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format a number to 2 decimal places.

Note that [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string so if you want to work with the result as a number again, you'll need to [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
function GetDiff (dt) { 
    sMins = " Min";
    sHours = " Hrs";
    sDays = " Days";

    if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) < 1440 ) {
        if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) <= 60 ) {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) + sMins).toFixed(2);
        }
        else
        {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/60) + sHours).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/1440) + sDays).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: its pulling the date out of a program it is connected to and as I thought your code would work it does not. Its pulling a Due Date out of a program. I got it to work with this although it only returns 1 digit after decimal. I tried your code screen goes blank.   return ((Math.floor(Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/1440)*10)/10) + sDays)

Comment: I don't see your call to `toFixed()`

Comment: its not there when I put in the .toFixed(2); the sections with that data disappeared.

Comment: Make sure that you're only applying `toFixed(2)` to a number, not a string or anything else...

Comment: maybe I need to implement the .parsefloat() how would I do that? sorry this is all so new to me.

Comment: Oh ya I think its definitely a string because I use the function GetDiff later down on in the code. for ex.     "if ( DateDiff ("n", TestLate, now) >= 0 ) { ReviewIcon = "<img  src='../Images/Red-Test.png' width='20' height='23'>"; TestIcon = "<strong><font size='"+sz+"' color = "+cr+">Late By " + GetDiff (TestLate);}"

Comment: If you have a string, for example `var str = '1.9876543';` then use `console.log( parseFloat(str).toFixed(2) );`

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n=num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need to round the values:

```
function GetDiff (dt) { 
    sMins = " Min";
    sHours = " Hrs";
    sDays = " Days";

    if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) < 1440 ) {
        if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) <= 60 ) {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)) + sMins).toFixed(2);
        }
        else
        {
            return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/60) + sHours).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return (Math.abs (DateDiff ("n", now, dt)/1440) + sDays).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927144/821056

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to round a number to two decimals

```
var original=28.453
var result=Math.round(original*100)/100  //returns 28.45
```

Taken from: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml

Answer (score -1):

Use a DecimalFormatter:

```
double number = 0.9999999999999;
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
```

Will give you "0.99". You can add or subtract 0 on the right side to get more or less decimals.

Or use '#' on the right to make the additional digits optional, as in with #.## (0.30) would drop the trailing 0 to become (0.3).

Comment: He's using JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: How would I input that into the code I posted. I'm real new at HTML