# Always display at least two decimal places

Tags: javascript, decimal

I want to format a number so that it always have at least two decimal places.

Samples:

```
1
2.1
123.456
234.45
```

Output:

```
1.00
2.10
123.456
234.45
```

Comment: Checkout http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: @DavidBarker The question you linked takes 2 decimals regardless if there is more, this is not what the op asked.

Comment: You can look at this question as a response:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could fix to 2 or the count of current places;

```
 var result = num.toFixed(Math.max(2, (num.toString().split('.')[1] || []).length));
```

Answer (score 13):

How about using [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) :

```
Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.language, {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 10,
}).format(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var num = 1.2;
function decimalPlaces(num) {
  var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
  if (!match) { return 0; }
  return Math.max(
       0,
       // Number of digits right of decimal point.
       (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
       // Adjust for scientific notation.
       - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
}
if(decimalPlaces(num) < 2){
   num = num.toFixed(2);
}
alert(num);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2MYQ/)

Comment: Output is `1.23` , I would want `1.2345`

Comment: Please try it again! Sorry about my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (working),

```
var a= 1,
    b= 2.1,
    c = 123.456,
    d = 234.45;

console.log(a.toFixed(4).replace(/0{0,2}$/, ""));
console.log(b.toFixed(4).replace(/0{0,2}$/, ""));
console.log(c.toFixed(4).replace(/0{0,2}$/, ""));
console.log(d.toFixed(4).replace(/0{0,2}$/, ""));
```

If you have more decimal places, you can updated the number easily.

Comment: This is maximum 4 decimal places, this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please see the last line in the answer. You can change this to any number of decimal places eg.

`c.toFixed(10).replace(/0{0,8}$/, "")`

First number is the max decimal places that we can have (10 in this case) and second number is max-min (8 in this case).

Comment: Alex K. answer is better because it doesn't set maximum decimal places.