# how to format a number into comma separated using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have these numbers 10010999.00 and 8094.456 and 456.78

And all I want to do is add a comma in the right place if it needs it so it looks like this 10,010,999.00 and 8,094.45 and 456.78 in the JSP page.

Comment: As far as I know it is impossible in css, You should use javascript. Or if you are using jsp you could format it using java.

Comment: @TomD'Hulster again, not really, that relates to javascript not CSS.

Comment: Seems like I missed the JSP part. Saw Javascript in the tags and assumed it was for Javascript.
Edit: I changed my name, Stengel was my previous name so it's the same person @RyanMcDonough

Comment: Ah no worries @TomD'Hulster

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via `toLocaleString()` function.

Comment: `toLocaleString()` is javascript, not css.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. It was proposed in 2008 as [Content Data Function](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting) addition to CSS3, however nothing came of it. You will need to perform this action in Javascript.

There is a suggestion on how to format numbers in JS in this answer: [Format numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)