CSS @counter-style similar to toLocaleString
Is it possible to have a list counter style that behaves like number.toLocaleString()? Or at the very least, show commas in the thousands places?
Basically to show like 1,234 (or ideally 1.234 depending on locale?)
I don't see anything like that as a Predefined counter style
What I'm really trying to do is to use CSS animations to animate a counter, ex here: https://codepen.io/wp-asdf123/pen/XWLVPyy - and I would like for it to show with commas (or ideally locale-correct) in the output.
It seems like the way to do it is with @counter-style in the content: counter(num /*, counter-style? */ ); part, but I'm not 100% clear on that.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Using JS is pretty much required. All supported descriptors are listed in MDN, and non of these directly or non-directly allows this goal to be achieved, even if only using comma without considering locale .
From what I see using a huge fixed set of symbols is a potential solution, but then the number of symbols needed to be defined will obviously be too large.
One possible, but very limited pure CSS workaround I can think of is to use 2 (or more) counters controlling each 3-digit segmant with pad: 3 "0". This idea is very limited because it will only work if the counter increment is fixed, and is a number being 1 or divisible by 10. The initial count needs to be 0 or positive as well. See below example using only 2 counters, and the counter is fixed to increase 100 for each list item. Since these is only 2 counters, it supports only 0 to 9,999.


@counter-style hundres-paded {
  system: extends decimal;
  pad: 3 "0";
}

.item:first-child {
  counter-reset: hundreds 0;
}

.item:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: hundreds 100;
}

.item:nth-child(10n+11) {
  counter-reset: hundreds 000;
  counter-increment: thounsands 1;
}

.item::before {
  content: counter(hundreds);
}

.item:nth-child(n+11)::before {
  content: counter(thounsands) "," counter(hundreds, hundres-paded);
}
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>




Hm, yeah I was thinking about maybe using .toLocaleString, splitting around /(,|.)/ and then rendering each chunk as its own element, and putting the , or . inbetween... maybe simpler (though not pure css)

Yeah, using JS is probably the way to go unless you have very special use case.
You can see the second answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28451197/9107694 that someone mentioned Content Data Function but it didn't make it through.

welp, thanks for your help.
Now the tricky part, how to render it with leading zeroes :cry:

Gets extra confusing in my example if you put the react key as an actually 'valid' value because it will re-render the element and break the animation (in case anyone ever comes across this...)
