# Algorithm of the amount with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an algorithm to format the amounts wrote in `jQuery`:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvma4m12/)

But, there are some bugs.

For example, if I write `900.800,00` and then I delete "9" the import remains `00.800,00`. How can I fix it? I fixed many bug but I don't know how to fix this.

Another bug arrives from:

```
$(this).on("dragstart", function(e) {
     return false;
});
```

It is used to prevent the drag the text inside the input field. But, after an `AJAX` call this not works more. 
I should use something like `$(document).on`, but how exactly?

Can you find other bugs? Thank you!

Comment: Your second question is answered fairly canonically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: If you need help with code, post a minimal example of code that doesn't work on the question. Links are pointless as they can go stale

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is to format `900.800,00` but this number is really just 900800.00 (american-style).

Steps:

1. Remove all number-group separator.
2. Parse the number so that it is machine understandable.
3. Format your number again

But beside that, this question has already been [asked thousands of time before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript).

And... [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) shows us that it's a "Solved Problem" that you shouldn't try to solve it again.

Answer (score 0):

About the second bug
Remember that any element create dynamically, won't be included in event handler.

I'll explain. If you have this event listener

```
$( ".clickable" ).click( function(e) {
  alert( "Clicked" );
});
```

If you add another element with the "clickable" class to the page, it won't recive the click event. To do that, you need to use the event delegation

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".clickable", function( e ) {
  alert( "Clicked" );
});
```

Now the click event will be locked to the document itself and propagated to all ".clickable" elements inside it. To have a "cleaner" environment you can bind the click event only on a certain container

```
$( "div.clickable_container" ).on( "click", ".clickable", funciton( e ) {
  alert( "Clicked" );
});
```