# How to format big numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, formatting, currency, biginteger

I have the following big number: `2.9364136545300044e+24` I heed to format this value to `2,936,413.65` value

How could I do it of are there any libraries to make it?

Comment: Convert the number to a String, and add a comma every third character from the right?

Comment: Yes. But I need to take care for smaller numbers also

Comment: Why would my suggestion not work for smaller numbers?

Comment: [Format numbers in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript/7125034#7125034)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format), `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.concat()`

```js
var number = 2.9364136545300044e+24;
var n = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number);
var res = n.slice(0, 9).concat(".").concat(n.slice(10, 12));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there polyfill for this API ?

Comment: @Erik What do you mean by "polyfill"? Which browser are you trying at?

Comment: I need to support IE9+ :(

Comment: The browser compatibility chart lists ie11+ as being supported. Have not checked for polyfills. You should be able to return same result using `.slice()`, `.concat()` alone; or alternatively including use of `.replace()` where the object and method are not supported at the browser.

Comment: I've found that `number.toLocaleString()` returns same result as yours `new Intl.NumberFormat().format` )

Comment: @Erik If that's a locale specific format though, I wouldn't rely on that. Different users may get different results.

Comment: I think @Erik is correct, as different countries expect different formats in a front end scenario. Some countries separate thousands with . and others with ,

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and easy solution you can use `number.toLocaleString()`.

Since, the localString is based on Browser definition different users may get a different results. However, you can force a specific location to always get the same format. Ex: `toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' })`