# Array formatting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Ajax call, the following `array` is returned:

[image]

What I want to do is, for example, format the `cpfsEnviados[0]` value to something like that:

> 16.982

How to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: `16982 * .001` ? Why is jQuery needed for this?

Comment: I look for some answers and saw some frameworks for this kind of task, thats why

Comment: @jvbarsou Will your number always be 5 digits?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @SankalpSingha actually no, those numbers are variables from my db. So matthew example is not flexible enough to support my data format

Comment: Aint ot more appropriate to perform this logic in the server rather than at client side?