# Does JavaScript support formatting numbers by string format?

Tags: javascript

In .NET I can format number by this code:

```
Dim num = 1234567.8933
Dim res = num.ToString("#,##0.00")
```

Result: `res= 1,234,567.89`

I want using this format `"#,##0.00"` in JavaScript. Does it support formatting numbers by string format?

Comment: Not built in, at least not like this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: [Format numbers in JavaScript similar to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript-similar-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want more complex formatting. You can have a look at http://numeraljs.com/#format

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> Does it support formatting numbers by string format?

We don't have built-in support to format numbers, but we have few options to get desired `#,##0.00` format like:

**Using [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):**

```js
const num = 1234567.8933

// To get only two decimal places use maximumFractionDigits option
const options = {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}
const res = num.toLocaleString(undefined, options)
console.log(res)   //=> 1,234,567.89
```

**Using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat):**

```js
const num = 1234567.8933

// To get only two decimal places use maximumFractionDigits option
const options = {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}
const res = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, options).format(num)
console.log(res)   //=> 1,234,567.89
```

Comment: This might produce the requested output, but doesn't answer the question of OP.

Comment: Thank you, but my format is not fix. it can change by setting.

Comment: You can use `maximumFractionDigits`  option to limit the fractions

Comment: Thank you , but numeral.js  can support change format by my setting.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, not out of the box maybe [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/#format) would help:

```js
var num = numeral(1234567.8933).format('0,0,0.00');
console.log(num)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intl.NumberFormat

```js
let num = 1234567.8933

let value = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(num);

console.log(value)
```

[`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to format :

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Change expression as you required. It addresses the dynamic formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here fixed upto 2 digit after decimal and use toLocaleString()

```js
let num = 1234567.8333
console.log(parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString())
```