# Adding digit spacing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

I would like to inspect a span element and check for its number format and apply digit grouping to it with jquery

It the number has more than 3 digits, that is for >1000, it must do digit grouping, to separate the thousands from the hundreds, and the hundred thousands from the thousands:

eg.

```
<span>5500000.00</span>
```

should become

```
<span>5 500 000.00</span>
```

Is that possible with jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6786040/1414562   just replace '.' by space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of formatting plugins for this task. Or use can use regular expression.

```
function formatPrice(price) {
    return price.reverse().replace(/((?:\d{2})\d)/g, '$1 ').reverse();
}

// Need to extend String prototype for convinience
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Tests:

```
formatPrice('1234.00')   // "1 234.00"
formatPrice('12345.00')  // "12 345.00"
formatPrice('123456.00') // "123 456.00"
```

*Maybe there is a way to do this without reverting a string?*

Comment: thank you very much. what would you suggest? I actually want to implement this on a knockout function (data is populated by knockout, but I cannot get it working...see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rRaHm/14/  - I can only do decimal placement, not digit grouping as well

Comment: Glad you didn't include "123.00" on the test. To see the difference change the space with a comma for the delimiter, you'll find the result something like ",123.00". But then again as we can see the question is about a space not a comma.

Answer (score 1):

This links might help :

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

[Javascript: Easier way to format numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726144/javascript-easier-way-to-format-numbers/)