# How to Set String format in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a string like

```
3500587
```

it's a product price and i want to know, is it possible to format it like

```
3,500,587
```

throw Jquery or not?

Comment: yes it possible in many ways.

Comment: @Pekka +1.  Google can be used here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043650/how-can-i-correctly-format-currency-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding digit spacing with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060016/adding-digit-spacing-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function for that. You can use either use a third-party library or do this manually:

```js
String.prototype.moneyStringPrettify = function(splitCount, separator) {
  var newString = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
  {
    if (i > 0 && i % splitCount === 0) newString = separator + newString;
    newString = this[this.length - 1 - i] + newString;
  }
  return newString;
};

document.body.innerHTML = "1234567".moneyStringPrettify(3, ',') + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += "123456".moneyStringPrettify(3, ',') + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += "12345".moneyStringPrettify(3, ',') + "<br/>";

// Just another usage:
document.body.innerHTML += "1234567890".moneyStringPrettify(4, '-') + "<br/>";
```