# text box decimal format fixing in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple text box and I am entering number value to this.And i want to format the number value to two decimal places and commas at appropriate place.Like If i enter the 10 in the text box and after pressing entering or leaving textbox it should be converted into 10.00. and if i enter 1000 in the textbox and after pressing or entering it should be converted into 1,000.00 Please tell me if there exist any possibility to do this using javascript

```
<input type="text" name="one" class="currency">
<script>
 $('.currency').live('keydown', function(e) { 
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which; 

      if (key== 9 || key == 13) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
          if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
        // call custom function here
      }         

});
</script>
```

This code will return output as 1000.00
But i need period and commas in their appropriate place

Comment: Do you want a solution for PHP (use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)) or JS? ... make your mind up

Comment: See [Javascript: Easier way to format numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726144/javascript-easier-way-to-format-numbers) for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
var price = 34523453.345
price.toLocaleString()

O/P "34,523,453.345"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numeral.js (http://numeraljs.com/) to do the job.

Example code:

```
var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0.00');
// output is 1,000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeCurrency(val){
    val = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
}
alert(makeCurrency(12743.7512)); // 12,743.75
alert(makeCurrency(12743)); // 12,743.00
alert(makeCurrency(12743.7)); // 12,743.70
alert(makeCurrency(1274340984893.1)); // 1,274,340,984,893.10
</script>
```

So you can just copy the function and replace `this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);` with `this.value = makeCurrency(this.value);`

Originally from [add commas to a number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery)