# Appending a string to datatables value and wrapping a value in a class

Tags: jquery, datatables

How do I append a string to a value in jquery.DataTables? e.g. I want to show `45.6%` rather than `45.6`. The data is coming from an array of objects where the percentage is as a decimal number rather than a string.

Also, is it possible to wrap a class around a value, (so I can style minus numbers in red for example)?

Comment: Or maybe you want to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726144/javascript-easier-way-to-format-numbers

Comment: @zloster or maybe you do?

Comment: It seams reading the question was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The docs for datatables isn't as good as it could be. Some digging up unearthed the `render` property for a column which accepts a function for formatting, so in the dataTable initialisation object :

```
columns: [
    {title: "Shown %", data: 'percent', render: function(data, type, full, meta) {return data + "%"}},
]
```

This also answers how to wrap a span around the value for styling!